# How to write rules engine for Azure Premium Verizon CDN, httpTohttps & SPA rewrite rules?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, rule-engine, azure-cdn, verizon

I have added my react build files in a storage blob container and enabled static website for that.

After that I have enabled Azure CDN classic ( Microsoft CDN ).

Below are the rules I have given for that.

First Rule is to convert the http to https
Second Rule is for SPA redirect.

[image]

It works fine. Now my client has asked me to upgrade the Azure CDN to Premium Verizon CDN.

But when I check the Rules engines, it's entirely a different UI. How i dont know how to add the rules that I added for the Classic CDN.

Here I am attaching the screenshot of the Premium Verizon CDN rules engine page.

[image]

its entirely different than the classic one. I am new to Azure and CDN.

Please help me to add the rules in the Premium CDN that I added in the classic one. I tried but no luck.

Your help is much appreciated here

I am trying to add the rules that I created for the Classic CDN to Premium Verizon CDN

Comment: Hope this documentation will help you [Override HTTP behaviour with Azure CDN - Verizon Premium rules engine](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine.md)   [Azure CDN from Verizon Premium rules engine features](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/cdn/cdn-verizon-premium-rules-engine-reference-features.md)

Answer (score 1):

- From the CDN profile page in your Azure portal, select **Manage** to open the CDN management portal.
- Select the **HTTP Large** tab, then select **Rules Engine V4.0**.
- Select **+ New** to create a new draft policy.
- Give the policy a name. Select Continue, then select **+ Rule**.
- Enter a name in the Name / Description textbox.

Refer: https://docs.edgecast.com/cdn/Content/HRE/HRE.htm?tocpath=Content%20Delivery%7CRequest%7CCustom%20Request%20Handling%20via%20Rules%20Engine%7C_____0

**Details on how to define source in Verizon rules engine:**

Refer: https://docs.edgecast.com/cdn/Content/HTTP_and_HTTPS_Data_Delivery/Accessing_Your_Content.htm

The syntax for source in Verizon rules engine is defined as below:
Content Access Point/Regular Expression

The content access point, which appears directly after the CDN hostname, allows Verizon CDN to identify the source for the requested content.

The base format for the content access point is a forward slash followed by a two digit number that precedes the account number. This two digit number is called the origin identifier.

[image]

**AN** in the above screenshot represents your customer account number which can be found in the upper right corner of the Verizon CDN management portal.

From your screenshot, **1A905D** seems to be your account number, so your content access point will be **/801A905D/yourorigin**.

[image]

- Now add the below rules:

**1) To redirect http to https:**

[image]

Here, you can either add the source as /801A905D/cdnendpointname/originpath/ for a specific path or /801A905D/cdnendpointname/ for the whole endpoint.

**2) For SPA redirect:**

**Points to consider here:**

The URL Rewrite feature defines the request URLs that will be rewritten. As a result, additional match conditions are not required.

URL rewrite can only be applied on if General Always match

URL rewrite feature includes matching criteria that must be met before it can be applied to a request. In order to prevent setting up conflicting match criteria, this feature is incompatible with the match conditions mentioned in the below doc.

Refer: https://docs.edgecast.com/cdn/Content/HRE/F/URL-Rewrite.htm#Compatibility

So, the URL rewrite in Verizon rules engine cannot be added with a specific match condition. But if you are just trying to rewrite a path or the origin, you can do so by the below rule:

[image]

Here, your originpath will be rewritten to a newpath and will include text captured from the source after that.

For example:
The URL rewrite rule is - source: /801A905D/cdnendpointname/marketing/(.*) and destination: /801A905D/cdnendpointname/resources/$1

When a request comes with
https://example.com/marketing/index.html

It will rewrite to:
https://example.com/resources/index.html

- Select **Lock Draft as Policy**. Once you lock the draft into a policy, you won't be able to add or update any rules within that policy.
- Select **Deploy Request**.

If this CDN profile is new with no previous rules or production traffic, you can select the environment as Production in the drop-down menu. **Enter a description of the environment and then select Create Deploy Request.**

Refer: https://docs.edgecast.com/cdn/Content/HRE/HRE.htm?tocpath=Content%20Delivery%7CRequest%7CCustom%20Request%20Handling%20via%20Rules%20Engine%7C_____0#GettingStarted

**NOTE:** Once the policy has been deployed, it will take about 30 mins for propagation. If you want to add or update more rules, you'll need to duplicate the current rule and deploy the new policy.